# If statement only working when else is the case

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The idea here is to create a sort of "EULA wall". For some reason, whenever I test this code if I don't have the cookie, it works wonderfully, the EULA pops up, the accept button pops up and the accept button gives me the cookie. However, when I have the cookie, nothing in the actual if part happens. I currently have three "commands" one that would bring up the button again (a visual debug of sorts) one that would pass text to a `<p></p>`, and one that would call a function that runs the open.window(); function:

```
</script>
<p id = "loc"></p>
    <script>
function printButton(){
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var text = document.createTextNode("accept");
            btn.appendChild(text);
            btn.setAttribute("onclick", "setCookie('accept','yes',365)")
            document.getElementById("loc").appendChild(btn);
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    location.reload();
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
            return "";
        }
    </script>
<p id = "testingstuff"></p>
    <script>
        function checkCookie() {
            var accept = getCookie("accept");
            if (accept != "") {
             newWindow();
             printButton();
             document.getElementById("testingstuff").innerHTML = "testing";
            } else {
    displayEULA();
    printButton();

            }
        }
        checkCookie();

    </script>
    <script>
function newWindow(){
window.open("http://google.com","_self");
}
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Seems bizarre that this sort of thing would happen but maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of `accept`?  If it is null, it will be not equal to '' which may be the problem.  Since javascript is pretty loose about "truthiness", maybe you could, instead, try `if (!accept) { } else { }`

Comment: Just want to note you don't need to say `<script>...</script>` after each function. A single `<script>` for all the function declarations is fine.

Comment: @mr Rogers, that does make sense however uppon further testing, your suggestion didn't seem to change anything. it shouldn't return null anyways, its designed to either return with a value (given when clicking the button) or return with a space instead.

Comment: Use `console.log()` [for debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx), it will give you more information about variables etc. E.g. immediatly after you assign `accept` have `console.log(accept)` to give you info on the accept variable.

Comment: @spencer Wieczorek, yes i am aware but this was all done while self teaching (i've never done JS in a web setting before, so this was all very new to me and i felt it best to kind of keep things seperate.

Comment: @jonp this is basically all being done in browser (via weebly's terrible html editor) so no access to a console that i'm aware of (maybe f12?). i know i should use an ide but im still very new to all this. ill give it a shot for sure tho

Comment: F12 in chrome will give you access to the console, which will alos display any javascript errors. Your current "debug" point should atleast be before the two function calls, so you know that your if statment is atleast being it.  Also I would not check for an empty string, you are setting the cookie to "yes" so check for that instead.

Comment: so, i checked the console, it is in fact returning "yes" which is what it should do. i have tried setting it to if(accept == "yes"){}else{} but again to no avail. for whatever reason anything between ){ and }else is ignored or something. checking the console showed no errors

Comment: Add `console.log("In If")` as the first line in your if statement, `console.log("In newIndow")` as the first line of the `newWindow` function and `console.log("In printButton")` as the first line of `printButton` to see where you are getting in the flow.

Comment: okay so, now its "working" in that the console.log(); function works on the other side of the if statement but the two tester still dont', not sure why O.O my intention is to have an window.open(); function there but whenever i put it there i get type error window.open is not a function

Comment: okay, so now its opening a window, but its just putting the url on top of the already existin url haha. i moved the check cookie to under the newWindow function because the console said it wasn't initialized or something to that effect. now the problem is that its not clearing the URL bar before trying to open the new window

Comment: made a tiny solution, it was replacing everything after the main portion of the url, with what i had in there. so it was mineclicker.weebly.com/mineclicker.weebly.com/mineclicker.html. so i just changed the window.open to mineclicker.html and it works fine now. so long story short, i shouldn't have called a function, from another function, that was called before the first function was initialized haha. lesson learned